# Apply Beautiful Soup to multiple txt files

Tags: python, loops, text, beautifulsoup

Grateful for your help.  I'm trying to apply Beautiful Soup to all text files in a directory.  The code below only applies it to one file.  Could someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import glob

path = '/Scripts/Demo_Contents/'

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt")):
  with open(infile, "rb") as f:
   text = (f.read())

  cleantext = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml').text

with open(infile, 'w') as myfile:
  myfile.write(cleantext)
```

Comment: Put the final `with` statement within the loop. As it is you're only writing the final file out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your indentation for this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import glob

path = '/Scripts/Demo_Contents/'

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt")):
  with open(infile, "rb") as f:
     text = (f.read())
     cleantext = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml').text
  with open(infile, 'w') as myfile:
     myfile.write(cleantext)
```